# Write an unambiguous Statement grammar that meets the following requirements:

Tags: grammar

Write a “Statement” grammar that meets the following requirements:

- skip is a valid statement
- Assignment of the form `x := E` is a valid statement, where x is an identiﬁer and E is an
  arithmetic expression
- The composition of two statements S0 ; S1 is a valid statement

I have the following solution, but am not sure if it is correct:

```
x:: E|skip|s0 E|s1 E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
S:
  SKIP
| ID ':=' E
| S ';' S
;
```

There must be another rule for E and SKIP and ID are lexical tokens.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  I'm not sure about what would be considered a "valid" arithmetic expression and what would be considered valid identifiers but how about something like this?

```
S   :: 'skip'
S   :: IDENTIFIER ':=' E
S   :: S | S ';' S

A1  :: '+' | '-'
A2  :: '*' | '/'

NBR :: '1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'0'
O   :: NBR          /* remove this if arithm. expression only on identifiers */
O   :: IDENTIFIER
O   :: '(' E ')'

F   :: O
F   :: O A1 O

E   :: F A2 F
```

Comment: It sounds like we can assume expressions are already defined as E, and don't need to be defined in the part of the grammar the assignment cares about.  I could be wrong, though.